# C binary expression with -Werror flag set

Tags: c, gcc, binary, warnings

I am developing a code in C with the use of the syntax :

> uint8_t a = 0b00000000

I also compile with the flags with GCC :

> -std=gnu18 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror

But GCC is returning this warning (set as error in my case) :

> binary constant are a GCC extension [-Werror]

I perfectly understand the warning (in my case set as error) but is there a way to erase this error (in term of setting for -std= or in the code) ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Only "solution" is to remove the `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: It is working but I still want pedantic to be present for other part of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, since there's no separate warning option just for this, it's not possible to use pragmas to temporarily disable it. If you need to use `-pedantic` then you can't use GCC-specific extensions.

Comment: In this specific case though, why not simply use `0` (or `0x00`) as the initializer? It's just as clear as `0b00000000`.

Comment: I am using binary numbers because I am extracting information from a buffer (with mask,...). Hex notation is an alternative but I prefer the binary notation because it is more "readable".

Comment: Another solution is to not use `-Werror`.